# Algorithm to see if two linked lists are equal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, linked-list

I have an algorithm which compares two linked lists, L1 and L2, and the elements that are equal, it puts them in a third list L3 while deleting them from L2. I am not sure though if this is all what the algorithm is supposed to do, and I don't understand some concepts such as "p1prec" for example. I want to know the design of algorithm rationally, the bigger picture. When I try to get the sense of it by examining the instructions one by one I feel like Im trying to memorize it. Also some advices on methods to design alike algorithms would be quite welcome.The algorithm is as follows :

```
    Equal(L1,L2)

    head[L3] = NIL            //L3 is empty
    if head[L2] = NIL         //if there are no elements in L2 return NIL
       return L3
    p1 = head[L1]             //p1 points the head of L1
    p1prec = nil              //p1prec is supposed to be precedent I guess.
    while p1 =/= nil
          p2 = head[L2]       //p2 points head of L2
          p2prec = nil        //p2prec is precedent of p2; first cycle is nil
          while p2 =/= nil and key[p1] =/= key[p2]
                p2prec = p2          // pass p2 and p2prec through L2 until
                p2 = next[p2]        // key[p1] = key[p2]
          if p2 =/= nil        // if two elements are found equal
                next[p1prec] = next[p1]          // im not sure what this does
                insert(L3,p1)                    // insert the element in L3
                p1 = next[p1prec]                //neither this,
                next[p2prec] = next[p2]  //connects the p2prec with nextp2 because p2
                free(p2)                         //is going to be deleted
          p1prec = p1      //moves through L1, if no element of p2 is found          
          p1 = next[p1]                         //equal with first element of p1
```

Comment: Are you looking if L1[i] == L2[i] or it can be L1[i] == L2[j]? where i!=j

Comment: it can be L1[i] == L2[j]? where i!=j

Comment: Is that a question or are you agreeing?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I guess your goal is to understand how to do this problem I will just try to explain the basic algorithm to you instead of telling you what each line does.

You have 2 lists: L1 and L2.

You basically wanna check each element from L1 with each element from L2.
Let L1current and L2current be the values you are checking.

You also need a L2Prec because when you delete a L2 element you need to link the prec with the next.

```
You start with L1current = L1 and L2current = L2;
While ( L1current is not NULL)
{
    L2current = L2; // you set the L2Current to the begging of L2 list.
    While ( L2current is not NULL) // you run untill the end.
    {
        You check if L1current == L2current;
        {
            // If they are equal
            You add the L2 element to L3;
            You connect L2prec with L2next;
            You delete L2current;
        }
        Else
        {
                L2current = L2next;
        }
    }
       L1current = L1next; // after you are done with the first element of L1 you
                          // move to the next one.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1) it seems it's removing stuff from both L1 and L2 but that's a minor detail

2) how much do you know about algorithms and data structures? Do you know how a linked list works? How to implement one? What types are there and what are the differences between them?

I'm asking this because with basic understanding of a singly linked list it is pretty obvious what `p1(2)prec` is, what `next[p1(2)prec]` is and how deleting from a singly linked list works.

Maybe reading about lists first should be the way to go?

3) basically as you said this algorithm iterates over both lists and if it find a common element it deletes it from both of the lists and puts it in a resulting list (the elements can be at the sam positions in the list but don't have to - if that's what you want, that's a different question :-).

A *singly* (this is important here) linked list looks more or less like this:

```
prec    p1   next[p1]
el1 -> el2 -> el3 -> nil
```

You can go only from left to right. Now let's delete "el2". But wait we are *at* "el2", then how do we change the pointers so "el1" points to "el3" now?

Well that's what "prec" is for in this algorithm. In a SLL you will change to where the previous pointer will point and that's it! You deleted your element:

el1 -> el3 -> nil

Why is this so? Remember when I said you can go here only from left to right? Well you changed the pointer from `next[el1]` to `el3` so the next element to the right it el3 and there's no way to visit el2 even if we wouldn't do `free` on it.

Here `free(p2)` also deallocates the memory used by the element from the second list. Notice that it only does that for p2 because p1 was inserted into L3 so we still need it.

Depending on the language/implementation this line:

```
next[p1prec]
```

Might be problematic. What if the first elements are equal? Then p1prec and p2prec are still nil yet you are trying to do some operation on them. But as I said that's an implementation detail.

4) This has O(n^2) complexity (if I didn't miss anything) because for each element in L1 you do (in the worst case) a full traversal of L2 (notice that after `while p1 =/= nil` p2 points again at the head element).

That's basically it...

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with lists. It's not that I didn't understand what a "prec" pointer would do generally but I was confused about p1prec because I was convinced that the algorithm doesn't delete the element from L1. So if you take that for granted p1prec would not be necessary. All is clear now.